# Why in C++ overwritingis is slower than writing?

Tags: c++, performance, stack, heap-memory

**USELESS QUESTION - ASKED TO BE DELETED**
I have to run a piece of code that manages a video stream from camera.
I am trying to boost it, and I realized a weird C++ behaviour. (I have to admit I am realizing I do not know C++)

The first piece of code run faster than the seconds, why? It might be possible that the stack is almost full?

Faster version

```
double* temp = new double[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    temp[i] = operation(x[i],y[i]);
    res = res + (temp[i]*temp[i])*coeff[i];
}
```

Slower version1

```
double temp;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    temp = operation(x[i],y[i]);
    res = res + (temp*temp)*coeff[i];
}
```

Slower version2

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    double temp = operation(x[i],y[i]);
    res = res + (temp*temp)*coeff[i];
}
```

**EDIT**
I realized the compiler was optimizing the product between elemnts of **coeff** and **temp**. I beg your pardon for the unuseful question. I will delete this post.

Comment: That looks a bit strange. How did you measure? Please post a minimal compilable example that reproduces what you're seeing.

Comment: _"It might be possible that the stack is almost full?"_ How should that affect performance in any way? Stack is just managed as a pointer, if it's full you'll get an exception.

Comment: The first version has a memory leak, so it should not be used in any case. But what you claim seems unlikely. Make sure to profile after switching optimizations on.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you compile this without any optimizations enabled?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That depends on the OS, and can fail far more spectacularly than an exception even on current OSes. Agreed that it shouldn't affect performance as long as the stack doesn't overflow, though.

Comment: Hm, maybe the compiler manages to do some SIMD on the first, but not the others?

Comment: This is a performance C++ question.  Like all preformance C++ questions, you need to include compiler flags used, platform, actual timings, and code that actually lets others reproduce your findings.  Or at least *one* of them.  Every c++ performance question here has people asking for those, or people providing those, nearly.

Comment: You also need to provide complete code, including what `operation()` does and information about what `res` is and `x`, `y`, and `coeff` are (e.g. are they arrays, lists, vectors, etc).    My guess is either some aliasing going on (e.g. `x` and `y` reference the same things) or `operation()` doing something that affects properties like locality of references (which would affect what can be kept in cache between loop iterations).

Comment: I realized the compiler was optimizing the product between elements of **coeff** and **temp**. Storing them in a vector made the computation faster. I beg your pardon for the unuseful question. I will delete this post.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the first version is considerably slower than the second for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has obviously nothing to do with "writing vs overwriting".

Assuming your results are indeed correct, I can guess that your "faster" version can be vectorized (i.e. pipelined) by the compiler more efficiently.

The difference in that in this version you allocate a storage space for `temp`, whereas each iteration uses its own member of the array, hence all the iterations can be executed independently.

Your "slow 1" version creates a (sort of) false dependence on a single `temp` variable. A primitive compiler might "buy" it, producing a non-pipelined code.

Your "slow 2" version seems to be ok actually, loop iterations are independent.
Why is this still slower?
I can guess that this is due to the use of the same CPU registers. That is, arithmetic on `double` is usually implemented via FPU stack registers, this is the interference between loop iterations.